# How to check date using calendar library if it is in the database using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I want to check the date i pick if it is in the database. If it is already in the database there will be an Update button and if not, only the choices will be seen in the modal.

**View**

**Modal Body**

```
    <form method="POST" action="index.php/CalendarController/savedata">

        <input type="hidden" name="testingcheck" id="testingcheck">
        <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="radio" value="event-important" id="testchecked" name="testchecked"> Normal Day
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="radio" value="event-success" id="testchecked" name="testchecked"> Day Off
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="radio" value="event-warning" id="testchecked" name="testchecked"> Sale 30%
        </label>
                <input type="submit" name="savedata" id="savedata" value="Save Data"/>

        </form>
```

**javascript and Jquery**

```
$('.cal-cell').on('click', function () {
                var proid = $(this).parent().find('span').attr('data-cal-date');
                //alert(proid);

                $('#events-modal').modal('show');

            $(this).find('span').each(function() {
                var cellObj = $(this).parent().find('span').attr('data-cal-date');
                // alert (cellObj);
                document.getElementById("testingcheck").value = cellObj;
                document.getElementById("datepicked").value = cellObj;

                });

            });
```

Comment: where did you do ajax code to check in DB?

Comment: i didn't do it yet coz i don't know to do it. Can you help?

Comment: ya sure, first show me your datepicker HTML code & show us, if you did any controller and model code for check date in db

Comment: @M.Hemant I am using this code [link] (https://www.roytuts.com/bootstrap-calendar-events-demo-using-codeigniter/) but I edit some functions like when i click in the cell the modal will appear

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check that the date is exits in database with codeigniter controller and pass it to view and on save but you can do it with update button like this.

```
<?php if($dateexits){ ?>
   <input type="submit" name="savedata" id="savedata" value="Save Data"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but first thing is you need to pass the date that you've clicked then pass it to the controller... Do you know how to do that?